# How to restrict a Web page to only open when a request for it comes from a specific referrer

Tags: javascript, http

I'm writing a new JavaScript based Web app, which I need to secure in the following specific manner:
I should only allow for my app's index.html to be served if the request for it comes from a specific site.
By doing that, I will be forcing my users to go to that specific corporate site first, which will require for them to authenticate. Once the user is logged onto that site, they are provided with a link to my app. If my app's index.html is requested in any other way, beside following that corporate link, I would like to redirect the user to that corporate site.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why not use something like OAuth ?

Comment: You can do this using the suggestions in the answers you already have, but keep in mind that Referer is just and HTTP header which browsers conveniently set, so it can very easily be spoofed. In addition, if your corporate site uses SSL (hosted under https://...) and your app does not you will not get a referer at all (RFC 2616: "Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol.").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use document.referrer to get the referral page. Once you get that from your corporate site you can probably put in some logic to redirect to the corporate site if it doesn't match where you're expecting.

Something tells me this isn't the best way to handle user authentication, but I'm new to that aspect.

Note: I'm on my phone, so excuse lack of code tags for that tiny bit up there.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to the `document.referrer()`.Then check the condition properly to determine if the referrer is in the proper page and if its not do a redirect..